# Comparing amount of variation due to different variables in ANOVA

Tags: anova, p-value

We have performed the same experiment under a bunch of different conditions, and now wish to know which type of change in condition caused the greatest variation in results. I.e., do results vary more when different people do the same experiment in the same location, than if the same person does the experiment in multiple locations. We are not interested in whether 'location' or 'experimenter' in itself has a statistically significant influence on the outcome, but rather a comparison of the likely effect sizes.

What is the best way to go about it? It seems that 'ANOVA' is probably somewhere in the answer? At first we thought we should simply take the 'mean squared error', but then we got to thinking that since the F-values and the p-values seem to take more information into account, those might be more accurate for comparing variables. It should be noted that there is a mixture of nominal and ordinal variables, and they have different degrees of freedom.

It feels like using p-values might unintentionally conflate 'likelihood of having an effect' with 'size of effect', but are those two questions meaningfully different when the answer is extracted from the same data set like this?

I hope the question(s) make sense.